# How can I know which certificate is able to decrypt a string?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

If I have an encrypted string

```
$cipherText ="MIID"
```

How can I figure out what specific certificate is able to decrypt it?

If I just decrypt it, like this:

```
Invoke-ServiceFabricDecryptText -CipherText $cipherText
```

..I'm not able to see which specific certificate was able to decrypt it

Comment: Have you checked this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security). @Jason Hunter

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me. I've read it, but it doesn't address how to identify exactly which certificate decrypts the string

Comment: It has different types of certificates, and their significance depends on the type of functionality in service fabric cluster. And it is quite impossible to tell which certificate exactly will be able to decrypt it. @Jason Hunter

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know which certificate is able to decrypt a string?

There is no direct way to identify which certificate will be able to decrypt the string. `Invoke-ServiceFabricDecryptText` is a command which only focusses on decrypting the text.

Check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security), try all the available certificates by trial-and-error method and verify which one will be suitable to the given decrypted text. (Not applicable for large number of available certificates as it makes job difficult)

In Service Fabric encryption, the encrypted string usually contains details about the certificate used for encryption, like its thumbprint. You can check the initial characters of the `$cipherText` variable to verify if there's a recognizable format that talks about the certificate used.

You can also check the manifest file `ApplicationManifest.xml`. The application manifest might specify the encryption certificate with the help of `<SecretsCertificate>` element.

Reference: [Manage certificates in Service Fabric clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/cluster-security-certificate-management)